# Updating Field using Field Calculator Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, update

I am trying to update my Status field as seen below:

[image]

I want to change the Null and Existing values to Permanently Removed using the Python Parser; however, I am receiving an error.

[image: Error message:]

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
def updateName(sCode):
    if sCode == Null:
       status= 'Permanently Removed'
    elif sCode == 'Existing':
       status = 'Permanently Removed'
    else:
       status = None
    return status
```

[image]

Comment: A couple suggestions: 1.) change if sCode == Null: to if sCode is None:   and make sure that the STATUS field does not contain coded values in its domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are so close. 
As mentioned by @mmore, use "is None" to find Null values.
sCode is the variable for Status, therefore use that for the final condition.

See the link on [how to use the field calculator.](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm)

```
def updateName(sCode):
    if sCode is None:
        return 'Permanently Removed'
    elif sCode == 'Existing':
        return 'Permanently Removed'
    else:
        return sCode
```